# Simple counting technique question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I am just getting into discrete mathematics and I am having a little trouble with this seemingly simple question. Counting techniques has never been my strongest suit, so I am trying to get better at it.

The question is: How many books must be chosen out of $24$ math books, $25$ CS books, $21$ Literature books, $15$ economic books to assure that there are at least 12 books on the same subject.

I am not sure. I thought choosing $13$ from each and that would add up to $52$, but like I said counting techniques is not my area, so any help would be appreciated.The answer is $45$.

Comment: Actually you don't need specify where you choose them from, just the number.  What would happen if you tried to pick 45 books in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, look at the maximum number of books you can have from each subject such that there are not $12$ books on the same subject. The maximum number is having $11$ from each subject - this is $44$ books in total. If we add just one more book then we are guaranteed to have $12$ books from at least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from a different direction. What is the greatest number of books you can choose
*without* choosing $12$ from any one subject?

You can't choose more than $11$ math books without having at least $12$ on one
subject (namely, math).
Same with CS, literature, and economics.

$11$ books in each of $4$ subjects gives you $44$ books.

Now what happens if you choose *one* *book* *more*?

Answer (score 0):

By [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), $45$ is the minimum required books.

$45$ pigeons and $4$ holes
one hole must contain atleast $12$ pigeons

Comment: could you please elaborate on that a little?

Comment: Ah sure :) Loosely speaking the principle states that if $n = km + 1$ pigeons are distributed among $m$ holes, then one of the holes will contain at least $k + 1$ pigeons. In our problem, we have $m=4$ and $k+1=12$

Comment: Duddee..that helps a lot. I had been trying to understand the pigeon hole principle for a few days. This really helps put things in perspectives